# How to automatically resize rowheight in table in UITableViewController in swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i am trying to resize row height programmatically in table in UITableViewController. i tried this

```
class MyProfile: UITableViewController {

    var details:[String] = ["collection","of","titles","are","written","here"]
    var subdetails:[String] = ["it", "is","a" ,"big", "string", "list"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return details.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let reuseIdentifier = "eachCellProfile"
        var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?
        if (cell != nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        }
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16.0)
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 10

        cell!.textLabel?.text = self.details[indexPath.row]
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = self.subdetails[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

i didn't add any restriction in table cell. i want to set row height according to title and title details string's length and font size. how can i do it?

Comment: For dynamic height, you have to ensure a complete top to bottom constraint is set. Do you have these yet?

Comment: Try set them first, else your OS doesn't know how to calculate UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 3):

Use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate height of each cell before it is created. Use the title detail string that you will use to find the height of and add it to a default height. In my case my default height of cell is 85 and font size is 15.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
var returnValue = CGFloat()

if (dataArray.count > 0) {
    let stringData = dataArray[indexPath.row] as NSString
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: 280.0, height: CGFloat.max)
    //get height of the string used
    let boundingBox = stringData.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)], context: nil)
        return boundingBox.height + CGFloat(85.0)
    }
    else{
        returnValue = CGFloat(85.0);
    }
   return returnValue;
}
```

This gave me dynamic cell height according to its content. Hope this helps